# função exibePar() em JS

Tags: javascript

```
function exibePar(n1,n2){
            while(n1<=n2){
                if((n1%2)==0){
                var par = n1
            }
            n1++    
        }

        }

       console.log(exibePar(0,20))
```

O meu código não está mostrando todos os pares ele só mostra o 0.

Comment: O que é "**texto em negrito**"?

Comment: erro meu desculpe

Comment: Qual é o objetivo dessa função? Exibir o primeiro número par? Montar uma lista dos números pares no intervalo?

Comment: montar uma lista de numeros pares no intervalo

Comment: O console.log não vai retornar os valores do while, ou vai?!

Comment: Então começa criando uma lista (array) vazia antes do while! E dentro, insere coisa nessa lista. Você criou uma variável que vai trocando de valor conforme percorre o intervalo.

Comment: nao sei achei que iria

Comment: O console.log é para mostrar o resultado final de uma ação, e não fazer loop, imagino eu.

Comment: aaaah sim vlw a ajuda

Comment: Faz o q o @bfavaretto disse, cria uma array e vai adicionando os valores com push.  Agora isso `(n1%2)==0` poderia ser isto `n1%2==0`

Comment: pode me dar uma ideia de como fazer isso se não for incomodo

Comment: Antes da função: `var pares = [];`... dentro do `if`: `pares.push(par);`

Comment: valeu agora vou conseguir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma array antes da função, assim terá escopo global:

```
var pares = [];
```

E dentro do `if`, vá adicionando os valores pares com `push`:

```
var pares = [];
function exibePar(n1,n2){
    while(n1<=n2){
       if((n1%2)==0){
          pares.push(n1);
       }
       n1++    
    }
}
```

**Teste:**

```js
var pares = [];
function exibePar(n1,n2){
   while(n1<=n2){
      if((n1%2)==0){
        pares.push(n1);
      }
      n1++    
   }
}
exibePar(0,20);
console.log(pares);
```

Answer (score 2):

Crie uma lista vazia e vá adicionando os valores pares com o método push. Depois faça um retorno do resultado desta lista. Ficaria da seguinte forma.

```
function exibePar(n1,n2){
    var lista = []  
        while(n1<=n2){
            if(n1%2==0){
            lista.push(n1)
            }
        n1++    
        }
    return lista
    }

   console.log(exibePar(0,20))
```